# Graphing a normal distribution with panda rolling standard deviations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, statistics

I am trying to take the distribution of a dataframe based on the rolling standard deviations.

I though about using [pd.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), but then I realized that it didn't allow for a changing standard deviation. Same issue with scipy.stats.pmf.

So I finally decided on using for loops:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web

data = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo')
window = 20

data['stan_dev'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window).std()
data['ma'] = data['Adj Close'].rolling(window).mean()
data.dropna(inplace=True)


data['difference'] = data['Adj Close'] - data.ma
bins = [0]*7

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(-3, 3):
        if (j*data.iloc[i]['stan_dev']) < data.iloc[i]['difference'] <= ((j+1)*data.iloc[i]['stan_dev']):
            bins[j + 3] += 1
```

Problem is, is its slow and I'm not even sure if it works.

Is there a more pythonic way of going about it?

Comment: Could you provide some data as well to make the snippet functional?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way of doing this, using the zscore:

```
data['zscore'] = (data['Adj Close'] - data.ma) / data.stan_dev
bins = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
cut_df = pd.cut(data.zscore, bins=bins)

ax = cut_df.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True) * 100
ax.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```